# Why can't I return a type as it's interface through an Expression.New

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to put Web API controllers in a separate DLL. I've overridden the default controller selection to pick a class out of my custom DLL but it's throwing an exception that my class does implement IHttpController even though it's clear it does.

My class looks like this:

```
public class GetItemController : ApiController
{
    public GetItemController() { }

    public string Execute(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The block of code that's throwing the exception looks like this:

```
public static Func<TBase> Create<TBase>(Type instanceType) where TBase : class
{
    NewExpression body = Expression.New(instanceType);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TBase>>(body, new ParameterExpression[0]).Compile();
}
```

It's called like this:

```
Create<IHttpController>(typeof(GetItemController));
```

The exception message is:

```
'CustomDll.GetItemController' cannot be used for return type 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController'
```

It seems like the expression it's creating should be equivalent to a function like:

```
public IHttpController temp() { return new GetItemController(); }
```

Which doesn't throw an exception when I just write that method so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: I don't actually have access to this code it comes from the framework. If i execute this same code though on a controller in the same DLL as the code it works just fine. It's as if it can't tell the class implements the interface

Comment: Hmm, I tried `interface IFoo` and `class Bar : IFoo` with `Create<IFoo>(typeof(Bar))` and it worked just fine.

Comment: I just did a test and if I move the class to be in the same assembly as that function it works fine. If the class is in a separate assembly it fails.

Comment: When I tried a system interface (`class Baz : IEnumerable` with `Create<IEnumerable>(typeof(Baz))`) it worked as well. Is it possible you're dealing with different two versions of the `IHttpController` interface?

Comment: I don't think so I'm using the ApiController class that I honk comes from System.Web.Http. I suppose it's possible that one is coming from Niger and the other isn't. I'll have to test that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Turns out as @p.s.w.g pointed out I was accidentally referencing 2 different DLLs. One in the main project from nuGet and a different one in the other DLL from the GAC. Everything was named the same so it wasn't immediately obvious but that was the problem.